# I have 9 Elements in the Map, but the distance between begin() and end() is only 2

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a problem in a code where I don't find any solution.

```
void Buffer::printAllBoards()
{
    std::cout << "Total " << boards_.size() << " boards." << std::endl;
    std::map<PlayBoard, InvVertex*>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = boards_.begin(); itr != boards_.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << "the distance is " << distance(boards_.begin(), boards_.end()) << std::endl;
        //PlayBoard board = itr->first;
        //board.printBoard();
    }
}
```

boards_ is a member variable of Buffer, and it has the type std::map< PlayBoard, InvVertex* >.

The output of the program for this part of the code is:

```
Total 9 boards.
the distance is 2
the distance is 2
```

The first line is obvious, because i add 9 elements to the map. But with the iterator I can only access two of them, because either the begin or the end function don't have the correct value.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Thanks for your answers.

I have provided the code as a download in tar.gz here:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-7931142/invers.tar.gz.html

Comment: Can you provide a complete, compilable example that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: I bet this is not the real code. Please **copy and paste** the exact code. NO CHANGE, not even a single character!

Comment: Since many `map` implementations use trees, is the `distance` method valid?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes. `std::distance` needs InputIterator, which is supported by all categories of iterators, as InputIterator is the minimal requirement on any kind of iterators.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: It has bidirectional iterators.  Why wouldn't it be?  `distance` works with input iterators or better.

Comment: In addition to the code (as Benjamin Lindley and Nawaz have asked), could you also tell which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: That's not so easy, because the project is a quite large Qt-project at the moment. However, in the given piece of code I haven't changed anything. I could send the whole code (about 10 files)...

Comment: And: I'm using g++ compiler version 4.7.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) the full code is not necessary, nor would it be constructive to slam a wall of code into the question. Make a copy of your project, then iteratively remove smaller parts that you think do not contribute to the problem and recompile and test every time. Normally you can either reduce the problematic code to ~50 lines or hunt down the cause of your problem in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have very little information but the only guess I can have is that `PlayBoard::operator <()` is not an [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), in which case `std::map` has undefined behavior.

For instance, the code below reproduces a similar problem. Notice that `foo::operator <()` is completely messed up and that's the cause of the issue:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {

    foo(int i) : i{i} {}

    bool operator <(foo other) const {
        return (i != 0 || other.i != 1) && (i != 3 || other.i != 0);
    }

    int i;
};

int main() {
    std::map<foo, int> m{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
    std::cout << "size = " << m.size() << '\n' <<
        "distance = " << std::distance(m.begin(), m.end()) << '\n';
}
```

The output is (with GCC 4.8.1):

```
size = 4
distance = 3
```

Comment: I already was afraid that it could have to do with the operator<. I'll try to change it and will see if this was the mistake. But thank you.